# How to check if your pieces are between A and B in c# using coordinates

Tags: c#, forms, coordinates

I need to solve the following for the last part of my game.  I want to check if all the pieces are between A and B (picture below) by using coordinates.

For example: `If(Blackpieces.Location == (between X1 Y1 and X20 Y20) {the coding i'll add}`

I'm more looking for this if statement but I cant find it anywhere, how could I do this?
[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by between A and B. Is that a straight horizontal line between A and B? Two sides of the board? Two sections just on the bottom part of the board?

Could you clarify on what A and B actually are?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] showing the code you have so far, and where you are stuck?  For instance, what types are `Location`, `X1` and `Y1`?  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*.

Comment: You  could define a Rectangle that represents the lower right quadrant of your board, then simply pass the Location property of your piece to [Rectangle.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_Drawing_Rectangle_Contains_System_Drawing_Point_) to see if it is within that Rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the direction of your axis X and Y, but you just adapt the relation inferior or superior

To test coordinates, you have to test X and Y like this (i suppose Location is x,y coodinates):

```
If(Blackpieces.Location.x > X1 && Blackpieces.Location.x < X20 &&
   Blackpieces.Location.y > Y1 && Blackpieces.Location.y < Y20)
{
   //DO Something
}
```